# Getting all days of that month based on the month and year I selected with the php date function

Tags: php, datetime

hi i have two selectors where i can choose month and year. with php how can I print all the day names and days of the month based on the month and year I selected?Please help me

```
 <form method="post" action="action_page.php">
    <select name="taskOption" >
        <option>Ocak</option>
        <option>Şubat</option>
        <option>Mart</option>
        <option>Nisan</option>
        <option>Mayıs</option>
        <option>Haziran</option>
        <option>Ağustos</option>
        <option>Eylül</option>
        <option>Ekim</option>
        <option>Kasım</option>
        <option>Aralık</option>
    </select>
    <select name="taskOptions">
        <option>2000</option>
        <option >2001</option>
        <option >2002</option>
        <option >2003</option>
        <option >2004</option>
        <option >2005</option>
        <option >2006</option>
        <option>2007</option>
        <option >2008</option>
        <option >2009</option>
        <option >2011</option>
        <option >2012</option>
        <option >2013</option>
        <option >2014</option>
        <option >2015</option>
        <option >2016</option>
        <option >2017</option>
        <option >2018</option>
        <option >2019</option>
        <option >2020</option>
        <option >2021</option>
        <option >2022</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get amount of days in the selected month and year. This can be done, using PHP function `cal_days_in_month`, or native function `date` with format `t`.
2. You should create a `for` loop, from 1 to amount of days in that month
3. Use PHP native function `date` using format `D` to print the day name, or you can use format `w` to get that week day number and map the number to any string you need.

A little example:

```
$month = 12; // 12 = December
$year = 2022;

$daysCount = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
// Alternative
// $daysCount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

for ($day = 1; $day <= $daysCount; $day++) {
    echo date(
       'Y-m-d, D',
       mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how do I get the days according to the month and year I choose from the options? Especially without specifying the month as a range myself.

Comment: I got this done. but when getting the name of the days it gives the name of the previous day. How can I solve this?Help me please

Comment: Try to set 12 hours, instead of 0 in mktime() function, may be timezone is the reason.